# smart table sorting accessibility

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Is there a way to improve accessibility by adding in the header of the column the state of the sorting in the aria attribute aria-sort ?

Something like:

```
<th aria-sort="descending" scope="col">
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Answer: yes. Your approach is exactly how it should be done. What was your question exactly? (I realize this is an ancient question and you've certainly moved on...)